# JS execution in WebView

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webkit, webview

How would one execute javascript code within a webkit webview on OS X when the page is HTTPS? It seems no matter what i try, HTTPS pages wont allow execution. Even something as simple as evaluateWebScript: doesnt do anything, and all i am trying to do is highlight a few fields.